# Merging DataFrames on a specific column together

Tags: pandas, for-loop, dataframe, concatenation

I tried to perform my self-created function on a for loop.

Some remarks in advance:

- ma_strategy is my function and requires three inputs
- ticker_list is a list with strings result is a pandas Dataframe with 7 columns and I can call the column 'return_cum' with result['return_cum']. - The rows of this column are containing floating point numbers.

My intention is the following:

The for loop should iterate over the items in my ticker_list and should save the 'return_cum' columns in a DataFrame. Then the different 'return_cum' columns should be stored  together so that at the end I get a DataFrame with all the 'return_cum' columns of my ticker list.

How can I achieve that goal?

My approach is:

```
for i in ticker_list:
    result = ma_strategy(i, 20, 5)
    x = result['return_cum'].to_frame()
```

But at this stage I need some help.

Comment: Have a look at the docs for pandas concat: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html  There is a join arg in there where to can indicate how you want to join the dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

If i inderstood you correctly this should work:

```
result_df =pd.DataFrame()
for i in ticker_list:
    result= ma_strategy(i, 20,5)
    resault_df[i + '_return_cum'] = result['return_cum']
```